# How can IE load an application for a specific file type

Tags: com, activex

I have an application that handles a particular set of extensions. If I want to be able to open that application inside my IE browser what do I have to support ?

From my research it looks like I will have to implement my application as a COM server and register a MIME handler. This way when IE encounters my extension it can use COM to load my application inside the browser and call my interfaces ?

Is this how its supposed to work ? I am thinking thats how pdf or msdocs get loaded inside browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Register an ActiveX Object as the Player for a Media Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751976%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

See also [MimeType.exe makes ActiveX object default MIME type player](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165072)